# How to make rotated <hr> line length adapt to page height?

Tags: rotation, line

I have a rotated hr line. See far right [here](https://sanitarygasket.org/wp/).

Is it possible to make the line's length adapt to the height of the page?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a script that calculates `letter-spacing`:

```css
#container {
  width: 50px;
  height: 500px;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

p {
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  text-orientation: mixed;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <p>My Text Here</p>
  <script>
    const container = document.querySelector('#container');
    const text = container.querySelector('p');
    const height0 = text.offsetHeight;
    text.style.letterSpacing = '1px';
    const height1 = text.offsetHeight;
    const spacing = (container.offsetHeight - height0 - 2) / (height1 - height0);
    text.style.letterSpacing = `${spacing}px`;
  </script>
</div>
```

Tried also `text-align: justify` with `text-justify` and it seems to be incompatible with vertically oriented texts...